# TcpListener Missing from System.Net.Sockets in monodevelop (not because of case)

Tags: c#, sockets

I have monodevelop install because of some work I was doing in Unity.

I thought I'd attempt to write IRC socket server/client with hopes for creating a simple IRC client in future.

I managed to get a hello world console app to compile but the following code that was copy-pasted from a tutorial will not compile because monodevelop complains of missing members of the system.net.socket library.

I included system.net in the references section of the project because before doing so it also complained that it couldn't load the system.net include.

Here is a screen shot:

EDIT - my reputation isn't high enough to post an image.

Here is the tutorial code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Net.Sockets.

            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
            int requestCount = 0;
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Accept connection from client");
            requestCount = 0;

            while ((true))
            {
                try
                {
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);
                    string serverResponse = "Last Message from client" + dataFromClient;
                    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Missing a reference pherhaps?

Comment: Why not use an IRC library for that? Writing networking code isn't exactly the simplest thing and is easy to get wrong. Especially when you start from samples like that :D In any case, your code compiles fine for me. Can you post the exact message you're getting?

Comment: After this line : TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888); message is : the type or namespace name 'TcpListener' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.Sockets' (Are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ok solution found : turns out monodevelop also needed "System" adding to the assembly references (I thought this would have been automatic because the hello world console app compiled just fine without it.)